# Download file to specific location through Java Servlets

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, servlets, download

I have the following servlet :

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/download")
public class FileDownload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FileDownload() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.sendRedirect("https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v7.8.8/npp.7.8.8.Installer.exe");
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

If I am hiting `localhost:8080/download`  automatically file is getting downloaded to chrome's download location. I need to download it at particular folder. How can I do that ?

Actually I need to install this file automatically through the code by another service. So that's why I need to download this file to a particular location, like common C:/users so that i can pick it up to install

Please help!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is completely up to the client. There is no general way to do this.

Comment: @tastaturtier actually I need to install this file automatically through the code. So that's why I need to download this file to a particular location, like common C:/users so that i can pick it up to install

Comment: You cannot. You simply cnanot control the client from the server and it is up to the client to select a location to store the file.

Comment: @M.Deinum but there are auto upgrade softwares, which download the file into some temp_dir of java  and during installation they are picking up frm the temp_dir.

Comment: Which is something totally different then a web-request downloading a file. You simply cannot control the target location from the server.

Comment: Ok thanks @M.Deinum . can  u please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260404/download-executable-file-from-java
It'd be great help!