# Download executable file from java

Tags: java, download, windows-installer, inputstream

I am able to download PDF,doc and other formats using below code. But when I try to download a `.msi` file from the URL/server location, I am unable to download it because `.msi` can not be converted to byte.

```java
try {
            URL url=new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection http=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            double fileSize=(double)http.getContentLengthLong();
            BufferedInputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(http.getInputStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(this.out);
            BufferedOutputStream bout= new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
            byte[] buffer= new byte[1024];
            double downloaded=0.00;
            int read=0;
            double percentDownloaded=0.00;
            
            while((read=in.read(buffer,0,1024)) >= 0 )
            {
                bout.write(buffer,0,read);
                downloaded+=read;
                percentDownloaded=(downloaded*100)/fileSize;
                String percent=String.format("%.4f", percentDownloaded);
                System.out.println("Downloaded "+percent+" of file.");              
            }
            bout.close();
            in.close();
            System.out.println("Download Completed..");
        }   
        catch(IOException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can u please help me out to download `.msi` file from link through java ?

Comment: @UmairKhan can u check now

Comment: works ok on macOS - what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Should work regardless of the file, make sure that the proper content-type is set when sending the file from the server.

Comment: @PrasadU , dummy file is getting downloaded like in the"out" I am giving path where i want the file to be downloaded. so after that dummy ".msi" file is getting copied.

Comment: @M.Deinum where we can set the content type in the above mentioned code?

Comment: You cannot, as stated the server needs to send the correct type. But the client just storing it it shouldn't matter it is just a stream written to file. What is the exact problem you have?